# Editing a scroll bar using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the color of a scrollbar thumb, which I know can be done using `::-webkit-scrollbar-track { }` in CSS, but in this case the color has to come through from a spreadsheet which I'm using JS to access.

I can't use anything other than plain JS or jQuery (no other libraries). Is there a way of doing this? Ideally something like this (I know this is wrong):

```
$('::-webkit-scrollbar-track').css({
    'background': /* data pulled in */
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `css` function is used for elements. `::-webkit-scrollbar` is a pseudo selector. However you can do something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('<style>::-webkit-scrollbar-track { }</style>').appendTo('body');
});
```